# Reversed Amazonian tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms, reversed-synonyms

I just noticed [a question about the Amazon jungle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-i-find-a-guide-that-will-take-me-safely-through-the-amazon-jungle) is specifically mis-tagged [amazon-river](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-river). Then I noticed on investigation that [amazon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) is a synonym of the more riverish tag.

Since we'll surely be asked questions about the jungle, the river, and the region, doesn't it make more sense to [amazon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) as the main tag? I might add a [amazon-jungle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-jungle) one too so that it can also become a synonym.

Answer (score 5):

It's a pretty narrow topic - why not simply have [amazon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) and no others?  I mean, would we really have [nile-river](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nile-river) and [nile-delta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nile-delta) and [nile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nile) as well?

How far do we go? [thames-river](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thames-river)? [himalayas-mountains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/himalayas-mountains) ?

My feeling  is that yes, you're right, [amazon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) should be the main tag.  But I'm not sold on the others existing.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Well you know as SE sites get bigger extra tags and synonyms appear anyway. Usually unless the new syns suck they just get merged as proper synonyms because it's a lot less work than rummaging around deleting tags from questions like I spotted you doing recently with a "travel tech" tag or somesuch that you could've just made a synonym of [tag:gear] with a lot less fuss.

Comment: But yeah we don't need anything besides Amazon. I just didn't want to step on any toes since it looked like some mod must've gone to the trouble of making the [tag:amazon-river] tag and making [tag:amazon] a syn of it since us normal editors can't do stuff like that.

Comment: I merely retagged it as gear since that's the one we have for those sorts of gadgets, tools etc.  It's vanished because there's a cleanup script that clears out orphaned tags.  In hindsight, making it a synonym would have made sense.  It must have been late :) I'll go do that now actually.

Comment: Was it just one question? I thought I spotted several...

Comment: By the way I'm trying to ask you on chat about how to find who created a tag, who added synonyms to it, when it was done etc. But I'm having a bit of trouble with chat right now too.

Comment: Yeah, I was too.  About tags - when I look, all it says is that 'Community' created them (the auto script). Which is frustrating, as I'd be really keen to know who made the most popular tags, just for fun :) I've googled it but can't work it out.  If you can find a link saying how to do it, if it's admin only I'll happily look it up for you.

Comment: The only thing I can find is a question on meta that shows how you can see via some of the badges you get for creating tags who was responsible for them. Oh and one of the SE guys saying he could might be able to divulge such information to certain people for tags used more than 50 times, and that Joel believes there's no value in letting people know who created tags.