# Gear or travel gadget?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, reversed-synonyms

I see that [gear](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear) has now been replaced by [travel-gadget](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-gadget).

But was this a mistake? I had a bit of a chat with Mark [in comments on another meta question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368/reversed-amazonian-tag-synonyms) and thought he was going to add the gadget tag as a synonym of the gear tag, not the other way around.

I'm pretty sure there are plenty of questions talking about non electronic type gear that use this tag and the more general tag should always be the primary tag shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark fixed this years ago. Ankur confirmed as much in a comment to a now-deleted answer submitted by RoflcoptrException.

This answer is just so I can accept it and thus show everybody the issue is closed, as suggested by pnuts.