# Tag cleanup - single-use tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have an absolutely ridonculous amount of tags, although not unexpected.

There are some single-use tags that should either be removed, merged, or synonymised. Add your personal pet peeves to the list, following the template, and update when/if an action is undertaken. Comment on the question as necessary.

---

- [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english)

  - Suggestion: **Remove**
  - Resolution:
- [sustainable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable) and [conservation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conservation)

  - Suggestion: **Synonymize**
  - Resolution: **Synonymized** [conservation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conservation) to [sustainable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable)

[galleries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galleries), [exhibitions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exhibitions), [museums](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/museums) and maybe more

- Suggestion: **Synonymize** to a common tag. Maybe [cultural-tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultural-tourism) or similar?
- Resolution:

[comfort](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comfort)

- Suggestion: **Remove**
- Resolution: **Removed**

[black-balsam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-balsam)

- Suggestion: **Remove**
- Resolution: **Removed**

[notary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notary)

- Suggestion: **Remove**
- Resolution: **Synonymized** to [legal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal)

[mile-high-club](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mile-high-club)

- Suggestion: **Remove**
- Resolution:

[third-world](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-world)

- Suggestion: **Remove**
- Resolution: **Removed**

[travel-sickness](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-sickness)

- Suggestion: **Synonymize** to [health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health)

[travel-gadgets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-gadgets)

- Suggestion: **Remove** or **Synonymize**
- Resolution: **Removed**

[travel-hacks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-hacks)

- Suggestion: **Remove** or **Rename/Synonymize**
- Resolution: **Removed**

[countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countries)

- Suggestion: **Remove**
- Resolution:

[extreme-tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extreme-tourism) and [adventure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure)

- Suggestion: **Merge**
- Resolution:

Comment: black-balsam can be removed with no problem. Unfortunately the only question concerning this tag was closed. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/how-to-judge-if-it-is-a-good-riga-black-balsam

Comment: You haven't left any way to vote or comment on individual issues without it becoming a tangled unreadable mess, or people just deciding not to comment for fear of making mess...

Comment: Also I think including a bit about what question they're used in might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Single-use tags are automatically removed after 6 months.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) So you don't need to go on a witch hunt, they'll die if they remain single-use anyway.

Answer (score 1):

- [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english)

  - Suggestion: Remove
  - Resolution: **Removed**
- [sustainable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable) and [conservation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conservation)

  - Suggestion: Synonymize
  - Resolution: **Merged and synonimised**
- [galleries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galleries), [exhibitions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exhibitions), [museums](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/museums) and maybe more

  - Suggestion: Synonymize to a common tag. Maybe [cultural-tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultural-tourism) or similar?
  - Resolution: Nothing done
- [comfort](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comfort)

  - Suggestion: Remove
  - Resolution: **Removed**
- [black-balsam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-balsam)

  - Suggestion: Remove
  - Resolution: **Removed**
- [notary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notary)

  - Suggestion: **Remove**
  - Resolution: Removed and synonimised with [legal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal)
- [mile-high-club](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mile-high-club)

  - Suggestion: Remove
  - Resolution: **Removed**
- [third-world](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-world)

  - Suggestion: Remove
  - Resolution: **Removed**
- [travel-sickness](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-sickness)

  - Suggestion: Synonymize to [health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health)
  - Resolution: **Synonimised**
- [travel-gadgets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-gadgets)

  - Suggestion: Remove or Synonymize
  - Resolution: **Created new [electronic-items](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-items), merged and synonimised [kindle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) and [travel-gadgets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-gadgets) to it.**
- [travel-hacks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-hacks)

  - Suggestion: Remove or Rename/Synonymize
  - Resolution: Merged and synonimised with [tips-and-tricks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks)
- [countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countries)

  - Suggestion: Remove
  - Resolution: This stays, there's a genuine use for it which needs to be clarified with tag wiki
- [extreme-tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extreme-tourism) and [adventure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure)

  - Suggestion: **Merge**
  - Resolution: Not to be changed

Comment: Just like the question I don't know how I should vote or comment on this answer `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail Say thank you for the hard moderator work

Comment: Umm thanks. Is it all done now then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to answer or vote or common on this so I guess I'll start by replicating the "tree" here:

- [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english)

  - Suggestion: **Remove**
- [sustainable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable) and [conservation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conservation)

  - Suggestion: **Make sustainable a synonym of conservation** because the noun looks better than the adjective
- [galleries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galleries), [exhibitions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exhibitions), [museums](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/museums) and maybe more

  - Suggestion: I think [cultural-tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultural-tourism) would be very ironic after [the recent debate](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386/should-we-remove-the-culture-tag) about the [culture](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) tag. Why not then just merge them all into the existing tag and declare it a bit broader and no longer controversial?
- [mile-high-club](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mile-high-club)

  - Suggestion: **Remove**
- [travel-sickness](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-sickness)

  - Suggestion: **Synonymize** to [health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health)
- [travel-gadgets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-gadgets)

  - Suggestion: Now this did at one point get merged with [gear](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear) but apparently it was one of the reversed pair of synonyms. It did look like it got put back the right way around [according to the meta post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/gear-or-travel-gadget), but apparently not since the tags are now separate. Anyway if [gear](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear) is a good tag, then clearly it should be the main tag. It is defined as: `Equipment, devices, and more—if you pack it, it's travel gear.` So you can see it was already specifically designed to cover electronic devices et al.
- [travel-hacks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-hacks)

  - Suggestion: **Remove** - I don't like it (sorry Mark)
- [countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countries)

  - Suggestion: It's purpose is to cover questions covering multiple countries and is best used for questions asking for help deciding between which country to visit. But in this use we also have the more general [destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destinations) tag. So why not just make [countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countries) a synonym that redirects to [destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destinations) and declare it to be used only for this?
- [extreme-tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extreme-tourism) and [adventure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure)

  - Suggestion: They're not really the same. Adventure is something unusual and probably lengthy like driving around Ireland with a fridge or crossing the steppe on horseback. Extreme is about putting yourself in danger like maybe diving off a cliff in Acapulco or travelling to a know war zone.

Comment: [tag:sustainable] and [tag:conservation] have been swapped around now.