# Too localized city tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

I found several questions, that mention a specific city and also are tagged with that city name. For big, popular cities like [london](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/london) that makes perfect sense, but in most cases they will get few question. I would stick only to country tag.

Examples of such tags: [lusaka](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lusaka), [kampala](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kampala), [bavaria](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bavaria), [parnu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parnu), [ko-phi-phi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ko-phi-phi)

All of them have currently only one question tagged and are not very likely to get many more soon.

There has been discussion before on single-use tags. 
[Tag cleanup - single-use tags](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/tag-cleanup-single-use-tags).
I propose a rule to avoid city or region tags, that are likely to become single-use.

Comment: Bavaria is not a city but the biggest "state" of Germany.

Comment: Lusaka and Kampala are nevertheless the capitals of Zambia and Uganda respectiely. I would not call that "too localized".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree. The number of uses of a tag is a poor measure of whether it is useful. Let's say I'm going to travel to Lusaka. So I search for [lusaka](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lusaka). Why should I not be able to easily locate the single post about that town?

[Single-use tags are automatically removed after 6 months.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) So if a city or region doesn't attract another question within 6 months, the tag will be deleted anyway. [This doesn't make much sense — there are plenty of legitimate tags that naturally remain single-use for a long time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki). There is no need to compound that automatic process with a witch-hunt. If the tags are so localized as you claim, they will disappear on their own anyway.

Comment: Did not know that about single-use tags.  TIL.

Comment: If ununsed/single-use tags are automatically cleaned, then my point is invalid. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7):

First, Bavaria is not a city but a state. And it is rather big and relatively well-known around the world.

While I more or less see your point, I think it's difficult to define city tags that "are likely to become single-use". How do you want to decide that? For example I think it is perfectly okay to use Bavaria as a tag, since the likeklihood that we have further questions about Bavaria is rather big. We already have some of them, but not all are tagged with this tag so far.

Additionally, in the question you linked, it is more about abstract tags, like travel sickness or countries, and not about city names.