# Tagging minor destinations by town, state, or both?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[Taiji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiji,_Wakayama) is a town with a population of only 3,255 people, in the prefecture of [Wakayama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakayama_Prefecture), which has a population of just under a million people. Wakayama is in Japan, if anyone's wondering.

Based on Japan having a population of 128 million, and having 98 questions, Wakayama "ought" to have 0.76 questions, and Taiji "ought" to have 0.0025 questions. Granted, the number of tourists a place gets, and the number of questions it gets, isn't strictly proportional to its population, and I've read that Taiji gets a reasonable number of bona fide domestic tourists. But I wouldn't expect a Wakayama tag to get overpopulated.

If a couple of locations in Wakayama got questions asked about them, and they were tagged by their town, leading to several single-use tags for locations within the same prefecture, would that be seen as a a worse outcome than a couple of questions being tagged by prefecture, leading to them using a shared tag?

Should a question specifically about a minor destination like Taiji be tagged by the town, the prefecture (state) it's in, or both?

Related question: [Too localized city tags](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/too-localized-city-tags) - heavily downvoted proposal. In this example, it would advocate neither a town nor a prefecture (state) tag, but merely using the country tag.

Answer (score 6):

For me when asking about a specific location you should just consider the travel aspect.

- If the location has any tourism or travel specific interest then there are likely to more questions in the coming years, so give it its own specific tag.
- If the location just has some one off or occasional thing but isn't a usual point of travel or tourism interest then:

  - If it's quite close to a place that does have tourism or travel interest, give it the tag of that place since that nearby place will surely attract future questions and the lesser known place is related to it at least by proximity (for sidetrips, local travel hub, etc).
- If the location is neither itself known for travel or tourism, nor in the close vicinity of such a place then:

  - "Zoom out" one region level. This could mean a nearby major city but more likely a state or province or named historical region. Different countries have different kinds of regions, like counties or municipalities, which may not be well known, especially to non-locals. In this case "zoom out" another level until a zone is sufficiently well-known. If you get all the way to a country and it's still not well-known then add it anyway, and perhaps also which continent it's in.