# Do not automatically expire single-use tags

Tags: feature-request, tagging

There is an automatic job that [deletes single-use tags after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418). No attempt is made at determining whether the tags are good and should remain, or whether the tags are a variant name of another tag and should be renamed or made synonyms. [Even beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153357/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-on-beta-sites), where it is expected that the tag system is still evolving, are not exempt. This job is not subject to any review, not even after the fact: one day the tags are there, the next day they're gone.

There is one way to prevent a tag from automatic deletion: [write a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) (which is a good idea anyway).

Given that a lot of tags on Travel are the names of locations which anyone looking for information would use, it doesn't make sense to remove them. Experience shows that [users are already hunting down low-use tags](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/tag-cleanup-single-use-tags), the automatic job is at most a minor help — and it does harm when it removes good tags. (How many useful tags have thus disappeared? There's no way to know.)

Please either:

- turn off the job that deletes single-use tag, and provide a log of past deleted tags so that we can add them back where appropriate; or
- provide evidence that the deletions were beneficial to the site (I don't know what form the evidence could take other than a log of past deleted tags so that we can ascertain that the tags were indeed useless in a vast majority of cases).

Comment: Sorry, we have no control over this. It's something that is common across all StackExchange sites. You've clearly done your research by linking to relevant discussions on MSO, but I think this question is best discussed at that site. Do you want me to migrate?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Actually SE people have told us several times over that their people keep an eye on all the meta sites. So since this is, so far, a specific request for our site, I think it's better off here. On meta.So/meta.SE (they're splitting real soon now) it will get bashed and kicked by passers by who are not employed by Stack Exchange.

Comment: How about a save the tag challenges? For each single usage tag try to get a second question.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException It's a bit silly, I'm not going to travel to <random> [tag:kosovo] just to save that tag.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee This is a per-site setting. Since SE have denied switching off the tag killer globally, I'm making this request specifically about [travel.se], which has many obvious good single-use tags. Since this request is specifically about [travel.se], it must be on [meta.travel.se].

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't know it's a per site setting. I'll ask on moderator chat.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/stop-removing-tags-that-are-only-used-once-in-the-last-6-months/5510#comment16278_5510, http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/questions/103/dont-expire-single-use-patent-number-tags#comment127_103. Oh, and http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=7004669#7004669

Comment: Add a tag wiki to the tag, and it will not be subject to the 6-month auto-burnination script.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Indeed, my feature request for that was accepted in the meantime. I've updated my post here.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Gilles' suggestion. However, this is not something that the moderator team can change on their own. [I pinged one of the SE overlords on our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7030704#7030704) and she agreed to turn this setting on if people agree here on meta.

So if you **want** that tags should not be deleted automatically, **upvote this answer**.

(Otherwise, downvote.)

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely some kinds of tags that need to stay even with a single use: destinations and airport codes. (The very same situation will occur on the new patents.SE site where all posts should be tagged with the patent numbers they discuss.)

In my opinion all other kinds of tags here should be subject to the automatic sweeping away of fluff.

What is apparently needed is some **tag meta data** that only diamonds or only some kinds of sysadmins at SE can set. Some sites including travel and patents have sweepable and non-sweepable tags. There needs to be a way for somebody to mark each tag.

Obviously we should still be able to decide to delete destination tags and airport code tags for some reasons which may come up, they just shouldn't be deleted automatically.